Application-defined error with Range function
VBA beginner here.
    Range("AL1").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=Macro!$F$6"
    Range("AL1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(x1Down)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

The code is trying to have cell AL1 be equal to another referenced cell in another sheet, and all other cells in column AL be equal to that as well. When I isolate it and run it in a separate macro, it runs fine. But when I add it to the macro I'm working on, it gives me the [Application-defined or object-defined error] message. All other lines in the macro before it runs fine as well. Debug pins to the second last row of Range function.
What is the problem here?

xlDown... the letter L, not the number 1.

Can be one line: Range(Range("AL1"), Range("AL1").End(xlDown).Formula = "=Macro!$F$6"
